# How to monitor Windows 11 taskbar message?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, winapi

Other application messages may be missed while I play games or maximize VMvare.
Is there a way using pywin32 to monitor windows taskbar red flash message like the picture below?

[image]

I just want to know this event.

Answer (score 1):

[HSHELL_FLASH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registershellhookwindow) can catch (denied) `SetForegroundWindow` and `FlashWindow`...